# Get changed item from DropDownListFor into another form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have 3 forms each has access to its own Delete/Create/Edit action on server side.

- When I change the DropDownListFor selected item and do a **Delete** then the string title is passed to the server
- When I change the DropDownListFor selected item and do a **Create/Edit** then the string title is **not** passed to the server.

How can I let my Create/Edit form know of my change in the DropDownListFor ?

Passing the initial title value works with the Create/Edit action. So the problem is the change event.

**index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Configuration.Addresses.ActionNames.Delete, MVC.Configuration.Addresses.Name, new { @area = MVC.Configuration.Name }, FormMethod.Post, HtmlAttributes.Form))
        {

            <div class="form-group required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, HtmlAttributes.Label)
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Title)
                                  .BindTo(Model.Addresses.OrderBy(order => order.Text))
                                  .HtmlAttributes(HtmlAttributes.KendoControl))
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" />
        }

        @using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Configuration.Addresses.ActionNames.Edit, MVC.Configuration.Addresses.Name, new { @area = MVC.Configuration.Name }, FormMethod.Get, HtmlAttributes.Form))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Title)
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default" />
        }
        @using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Configuration.Addresses.ActionNames.Add, MVC.Configuration.Addresses.Name, new { @area = MVC.Configuration.Name }, FormMethod.Get, HtmlAttributes.Form))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Title)
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
        }
```

Comment: what is set in title variable when you select create and edit ?

Comment: You don't have a dropdown in the 2nd an 3rd forms. Not to mention your generating invalid html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can use 1 form with multiple buttons**, you will achieve the desired result and your view will be cleaner.

As far as I know there are two main methods:

- 1 MVC Action: You can check the value of clicked submit button in MVC action and then perform the desired things. Example given that your buttons have as name "submitButtonName".

`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(string submitButtonName, YourFormModel model)
{
  switch (submitButtonName) {
    case "create":
      CreateMethod(model);
      break;
    case "edit":
      EditMethod(model);
      break;
    case "delete":
      DeleteMethod(model);
      break;
  }
}`

- 3 MVC Actions: You can change the form target action on button click using javascript. Example given that your buttons have as class "submitButtonClass".

  `$(".submitButtonClass").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#yourFormId').attr('action', $(this).val()).submit();
  });`

I wrote the code quickly without testing it but it should work :)

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: I know... but with one form how do you declare 3 different mvc actions?

Comment: The ONE mvc action will not work or has only drawbacks: 1.) I do not have  edit/add in the url but YourAction... the user might ask what is it? edit or add... 2.) I need a return statement for the YourAction when no case in the switch/case is hit else I ca not compile.

Comment: I will try the way with my 3 existing actions and catch the click, BUT I will do $('#yourFormId').attr('action',$(this).attr('name')).submit(); because my buttons are localized.

Comment: Forget about the last attr name comment value is fine!

Comment: @Pascal I found your 2nd comment a bit weird. 1) as a user I never see the code of a button: i just read the text. 2) you will need the return anyway even if you have 3 different actions.

Comment: @I just found out when I have ONE form but 3 actions (1 Delete is HttpGet and 2 are HttpPost) that does not work because my form is always HttpGet or HttpPost :/ that means I need more javascript to switch the FormMethod. You have a better idea? Else it does not find the two other actions...

Comment: Ok forget about the Verb, I made all HttpPost as its also Http-Like to get data with a post above all with complex data in http body which does not work for HttpGet!

Comment: Yes, regardless the number of actions, they should be decorated with [HttpPost] because in your code the form submit generates a post request.

Comment: Hi @Pascal! Have you implemented all the changes? Does it work as desired?

Comment: @Pascal, my pleasure! If you find other methods please let me know ;)